# Tradingview strategy, many orders are exiting when an order in the opposite direction is entered

Tags: pine-script

Might be a rookie question but I honestly don't know why this is happening. Pyramiding is default, so zero, but pyramiding only prevents more than one order in the same direction. I have a strategy written based on the Ichimoku Cloud and it can enter long and short. When I check the chart and strategy tester, a lot of these orders (but not all) are being exited when an order in another direction is entered. So a long's being exited when a short is entered, and vice versa.

I've included relevant code below.

```
//Variable for ATR, take profit/stop loss multipliers
ATR=atr(14)
TPmult = input(4, "Take Profit Multiplier (of ATR)", input.integer, minval=1, confirm=true, step=0.1) 
SLmult = input(2, "Stop Loss Multiplier (of ATR)", input.integer, minval=1, confirm=true, step=0.1)

//Variables for entry conditions
enterlong=(leadLine1 > leadLine2) and (close > leadLine1 and leadLine2) and (conversionLine > baseLine)
entershort=(leadLine1 < leadLine2) and (close < leadLine1 and leadLine2) and (conversionLine < baseLine)

//Stop losses and take profits
long_stop_level = iff(enterlong, close - (ATR * SLmult), na)
long_profit_level = iff(enterlong, close + (ATR * TPmult), na)

short_stop_level = iff(entershort, close + (ATR * SLmult), na)
short_profit_level = iff(entershort, close - (ATR * TPmult), na)


//entries and exits
strategy.entry("Long Entry", long=true, when=enterlong)
strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long Entry", stop=long_stop_level, limit=long_profit_level)

strategy.entry("Short Entry", long=false, when=entershort)
strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short Entry", stop=short_stop_level, limit=short_profit_level)
```

Anyway I can fix this? Thanks in advance. I want a long and short order to be open at the same time. I've tried setting pyramiding to 1 and 2 and it didn't fix it.

Comment: There is not possible to have long & short position simultaneously.

Comment: Huh, really? I never knew. Thanks for letting me know, I guess.